# Antd modal not opening / closing when using MobX state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, mobx

I have a simple MobX store that has a bool var contactFormOpen and function to set setContactFormOpen. It is working when clicking outside the modal or on cancel I can see that it changes but the modal doesn't open or close.

```
const handleCancel = (e: any) => {
e.stopPropagation();
store.setContactFormOpen(false);
};

return (
    <Modal title="Contact us" visible={store.contactFormOpen} width={740} centered footer={null} onCancel={(e) => handleCancel(e)}>
        <h1>Contact form</h1>
    </Modal>
)
```

In the console log I can see that `store.contactFormOpen` is changing from true to false, but the modal is not closing or opening. Any ideas? Thanks!

The store :

```
export default class store {
contactFormOpen = false;

constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
}

setContactFormOpen = (isOpen: boolean) => {
    this.contactFormOpen = isOpen;
}
 }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the store variable from?

Comment: From a mobx store export default class store {
    contactFormOpen = false;
    
    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    setContactFormOpen = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        this.contactFormOpen = isOpen;
    }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to understand what your application looks like from your description, but it's clear that you missed at least one important thing: for a component to know about changes to the store, it must be wrapped in an observer.

I reproduced approximately your application and here is a link where you can see how it should be implemented:

[Codesandbox link >](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-monad-k1royp)

Answer (score -1):

Mmmh sounds strange. Can you add this code and tell me if it works ?

```
  const [openContactForm,setOpenContactForm] = useState(false)

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(openContactForm !== store.contactFormOpen) {
      setOpenContactForm(store.contactForm)
    }
  },[store.contactFormOpen])
```

And change your JSX to this:

```
<Modal title="Contact us" visible={openContactForm} width={740} centered footer={null} onCancel={(e) => handleCancel(e)}>
  <h1>Contact form</h1>
</Modal>
```